# Why is ggplot geom_ribbon / area failing with facets & coord_polar with specific data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have a faceted plot using votes from the UN. The facets are split by country and issue.  It all works fine except when I include Korea / Palestinian conflict.  When that is included, either on its own or with others, it throws the error

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "dist", value = NA_real_) : 
replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

I've looked at the data for Korea and can't see anything that would cause the issue.  However, if I don't merge FDR and Germany, I get a similar error there.  So it seems to be related to not having data for the full period.

If I remove the coord_polar or faceting or replace the geom with a geom_line, then it works OK.  I have included a reproducible snippet of my code below.  The version there works, but if you change:

country_code != "KR" to country_code >= "KR" or similar, it will produce the error

Although it looks like I could replace the geom_ribbon with geom_area, the full version of this has other geom_ribbons and I need to keep them.

This is how looks when Korea / Palestinian conflict is excluded:

[image: How the facets look with Korea / Palestinian conflict excluded]

Any thoughts welcome...

```
# Load packages
#install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, lubridate, stringi, 
               unvotes)

# Power Rankings
# https://www.usnews.com/news/best-countries/power-rankings
powerCountries <- c("US", "RU", "CN", "DD", "DE", "GB", "FR", "JP", "IL", "KR", "SA")

votes <- un_votes %>%
  # Get details of vote including date
  left_join(un_roll_calls, by = "rcid") %>% 
  # Get issue for each one
  left_join(un_roll_call_issues, by = "rcid") %>% select(-short_name) %>%
  filter(country_code %in% powerCountries) %>%
  # Merge FDR & Germany
  mutate(country_code = if_else(country_code %in% c("DD", "DE"), "DE", country_code),
         country = if_else(country_code == "DE", "Germany", country)) %>%
  mutate(year = lubridate::year(date)) 

# Get just UK votes
ukVotesByIssue <- votes %>% 
  filter(country_code == "GB") %>%
  group_by(rcid, issue, vote) %>%
  rename(ukVote = vote) %>%
  summarise() 

# And pair them with others
ukVotesPairedWithOthers <- ukVotesByIssue %>% 
  left_join(votes %>% rename(countryVote = vote), by = c("issue", "rcid")) %>%
  select(rcid, issue, ukVote, country_code, country, countryVote, year)

# Compare and group
ukVotesVariance <- ukVotesPairedWithOthers %>%
  mutate(comparison = case_when(
    ukVote == "yes" & (countryVote == "no" | countryVote == "abstain") ~ "UK+",
    (ukVote == "no" | ukVote == "abstain") & countryVote == "yes" ~ "UK-",
    ukVote == countryVote ~ "Same",
    TRUE ~ "Other"
  )) %>%
  # Remove ones without an issue
  filter(!is.na(issue)) %>%
  group_by(country, country_code, 
           issue, year, 
           comparison) %>%
  summarise(count = n())

# Filter down to the ones we want to visualise
# Exclude Korea / Palestinian conflict as for some reason, the following error is displayed if is included
# Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "dist", value = NA_real_) : 
#   replacement has 1 row, data has 0
data <- ukVotesVariance %>% filter(comparison %in% c("UK+", "UK-", "Same") & country_code != "GB" & (country_code != "KR" | issue != "Palestinian conflict"))

ggplot() +
  geom_ribbon(data = data %>% filter(comparison == "UK+"), aes(x = year, ymin = 0, ymax =  count, fill = comparison), colour = NA) +
  coord_polar(direction=1) +
  facet_grid(vars(issue), vars(country),
           labeller = label_wrap_gen(width = 20, multi_line = TRUE))
```

Comment: OP, I'm not getting any error.  What line has to change/be excluded to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Change data <- ukVotesVariance %>% filter(comparison %in% c("UK+", "UK-", "Same") & country_code != "GB" & (country_code != "KR" | issue != "Palestinian conflict")) to data <- ukVotesVariance %>% filter(comparison %in% c("UK+", "UK-", "Same") & country_code != "GB" & (country_code >= "KR" | issue != "Palestinian conflict")). i.e. the country_code != "KR" to country_code >= "KR"

Comment: Error is indicating your data has 0 rows, which means it's an issue with your filter output.  Seems to make sense to me you would get this, since `data$country_code` is a character vector.  How do you want the code to evaluate `data$country_code >= "KR"`?  You're evaluating two strings with a greather than or equal to operator.  Type `data$country_code >= "KR"` into your console and you'll see you get nothing but `FALSE`.

Comment: In the first case, you have `country_code >= "KR"` also, but that's in the form of `expr 1 & (expr 2 | expr 3)`.  If `exp 2` is the one in question, it's always `FALSE`, but you'll still get some `TRUE` values from that expression as long as there are cases where `expr 1` and `expr 3` are both `TRUE`.  You can never get `TRUE` when you just evaluate `expr 2`, so that's why you will always have a dataset without any data.

Comment: The != and >= are just methods to exclude Korea (which removes the error) or include Korea with any or all others (which shows the error).  I did this to narrow it down the portion of data that refers to Korea and the Palestinian conflict.  The full version should not exclude either (but if I don't, I get the error).

Comment: Wait... now I see it.  Ultimately you're right, `>=` should evaluate the same as `!=` for characters... and you're seeing it work in one case but give you an error in the other.

Comment: Nevermind - `>=` does not work the same as `!=`, but you still get the error if you try to plot with `ukVotesVariance`.  Problem is not with the filtering specifically, but highlights what might be the issue.

Comment: I see now... the issue is *only* when you try to plot KR and the Palestine conflict.  For whatever reason, that does not want to plot correctly.  Call me stumped too.

Comment: Not just me then :)

Comment: Nope - Figured it out.  Gimme a sec to write it up for you.

Comment: That’s exciting. Where about in the world are you? I always like to ask so I can enjoy the global nature of this.

Comment: US - East cost :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP, this was a fascinating venture into debugging and problem-solving.  I'll get right to the point:

The issue seems to be that the transformation to `coord_polar` requires more than one point for a particular drawing in `geom_ribbon`.  That means that all of the permutations of `geom_ribbon` that need to be drawn **must have at least 2 values for y along your x axis** (or no data points at all) or you will get the error message.  In your dataset, we have one such scenario:

```
> as.data.frame(data %>%
    filter(country_code=='KR',
    issue=='Palestinian conflict',
    comparison=='UK+'))

      country country_code                issue year comparison count
1 South Korea           KR Palestinian conflict 2012        UK+     1
```

The issue really is that `coord_polar()` doesn't know how to transform this, yet `geom_ribbon` itself works just fine.  If you remove `coord_polar()`, it works just fine even though there is the one case that includes only one data point (ignore the unformatted x axis stuff):

```
data <- ukVotesVariance %>% filter(comparison %in% c("UK+", "UK-", "Same"))

ggplot() +
  geom_ribbon(data=data, aes(x = year, ymin = 0, ymax =  count, fill=comparison)) +
  # coord_polar(direction=1) +
  facet_grid(vars(issue), vars(country),
             labeller = label_wrap_gen(width = 20, multi_line = TRUE))
```

[image]

The problem arises when you add back `coord_polar()`.  Yet, we can still show a perfectly fine plot if we remove the `fill` aesthetic specification, since removing this detail will no longer create the scenario where a polar transformation is applied to a specific layer of `geom_ribbon` in your final plot.

```
# this code works, no reason to show the plot
ggplot() +
  geom_ribbon(data=data, aes(x = year, ymin = 0, ymax =  count), fill='gray') +
  coord_polar(direction=1) +
  facet_grid(vars(issue), vars(country),
             labeller = label_wrap_gen(width = 20, multi_line = TRUE))
```

### Solution:

The solution is to give another point so that the polar transformation can work in your specific case that currently only has 1 data point.  Since the datapoint in question is for a point in 2012, I decided to add another line where I specified `count=0` in `year=2013`.  This defines a "line" from `count=1` to `count=0` that can be transformed in the final plot without error.

```
data <- ukVotesVariance %>% filter(comparison %in% c("UK+", "UK-", "Same"))
x <- data.frame(country='South Korea', country_code='KR', issue='Palestinian conflict', year=2013, comparison='UK+', count=0)
data <- rbind(data, x)
```

When you plot, it works!

```
ggplot() +
  geom_ribbon(data=data, aes(x = year, ymin = 0, ymax =  count, fill = comparison)) +
  coord_polar(direction=1) +
  facet_grid(vars(issue), vars(country),
             labeller = label_wrap_gen(width = 20, multi_line = TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant @chemdork123, that all makes sense and thank you for digging into and solving it.

Comment: Now we all know a bit more on what's required for a polar transformation.